# how to test CI/CD pipeline stages?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, travis-ci, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way/framework (preferably in JS) to test for the correct execution of the CI/CD pipeline.
The usage would be to test that jenkinsfile/travis.yml executes the correct number of stages, and it also executes them in a specific order.

Comment: [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/lesfurets/JenkinsPipelineUnit) is probably the closest.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has an inbuilt command line tool that would help in trouble diagnosis and show what is happening in the background while the jobs run.

The out put would show which stage and jobs have been run.